# Datalist : detect if event input is launched by a click on item or a Key pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

```js
 $("#football_players").bind('input', function (ev) {
                alert("I want to know what is event launcher");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <datalist id="datalist_football_players">
    <option value="Maradona" />
    <option value="Pele" />
    <option value="Platini" />
    <option value="Cruif" />
    <option value="Messie" />
</datalist>
<input id="football_players" list="datalist_football_players" />
```

I have a datalist for giving autosuggestion to an input text and I would like to know when an item of that Datalist has been clicked, I can do it thanks to event input like that:

HTML:

```
 <datalist id="datalist_football_players">
      <option value="Maradona" />
      <option value="Pele" />
      <option value="Platini" />
      <option value="Cruif" />
      <option value="Messie" />
</datalist>

<input id="football_players" list="datalist_football_players" />
```

JS:

```
$("#football_players").bind('input', function (ev) {
    console.log("input event has been launched by click or by key press??");
});
```

Unfortunately Key press already launch the event input and I cannot know if event input has been launched by click or key press

Do you know a way to determine and if yes a way to know which key has been  pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may catch by checking event by binding appropriate events on appropriate target..
When a textbox have some typed values and then click is done , then a backspace keydown event is triggered too

So try following -

```
var eventKey=null;
$("#football_players").bind('keydown', function (ev) {
 eventKey=ev.which;
});
$("#football_players").bind('input', function (ev) {
    if(eventKey==null || (""==$(this).val() && eventKey==8 ))
    console.log("click");
    else
    console.log("key pressed"+eventKey);

    eventKey=null;
});
```

**LIVE** http://jsfiddle.net/mailmerohit5/q9dy5xL0/

Comment: thank you for answering but ev.which is always equals to undefined, whatever event is launched by click or by key pressed

Comment: no, unfortunately, even after testing your code I saw it doesn't work because event are triggering at same time and we cannot know what code will be executed before the other

Comment: goog point @user3540752 , let me chek it out and creating a jsfiddle

Comment: moreover you cannot bind a click on a datalist

Comment: Id is good! Thank you and congratulation for beeing so obstinate!